# Windows terminal opens two windows

Tags: windows, terminal, windows-terminal

I have a Windows Terminal v 1.17.11461.0 running on Windows 10.

When launching, *two* new terminal windows open. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/13272).

Open `settings` > `Open JSON file`. There is `"firstWindowPreference": "persistedWindowLayout"` setting enabled.

Switch that to `"firstWindowPreference": "defaultProfile"`.